# Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I adding tableView on viewController.
When I open this screen, then I will get the below warning once.

> [TableView] Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its
> visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy
> (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a
> window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table view to
> load and perform layout without accurate information (e.g. table view
> bounds, trait collection, layout margins, safe area insets, etc), and
> will also cause unnecessary performance overhead due to extra layout
> passes. Make a symbolic breakpoint at
> UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy to catch this in the
> debugger and see what caused this to occur, so you can avoid this
> action altogether if possible, or defer it until the table view has
> been added to a window. Table view: <UITableView: 0x7fe2ba8d5a00;
> frame = (-47 -80; 394 553); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM;
> gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003447480>; layer = <CALayer:
> 0x600003aa2be0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {394, 176};
> adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource:
> <Project.MondayToSundayViewController: 0x7fe2b9da05c0>>

When added symbolic breakpoint for UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy then below is shown in the console.

```
> UIKitCore`UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy:
->  0x7fff48260c7e <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff48260c7f <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff48260c82 <+4>:   pushq  %r14
    0x7fff48260c84 <+6>:   pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff48260c85 <+7>:   subq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x7fff48260c89 <+11>:  callq  *0x3e51a6a1(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff51411350: objc_retain
    0x7fff48260c8f <+17>:  movq   %rax, %rbx
    0x7fff48260c92 <+20>:  leaq   0x416a8dbf(%rip), %rdi    ; _UIInternalPreference_UITableViewEnableAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy
    0x7fff48260c99 <+27>:  leaq   0x3e5a2140(%rip), %rsi    ; @"UITableViewEnableAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy"
    0x7fff48260ca0 <+34>:  callq  0x7fff482a7529            ; _UIInternalPreferenceUsesDefault
    0x7fff48260ca5 <+39>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff48260ca7 <+41>:  jne    0x7fff48260cb3            ; <+53>
    0x7fff48260ca9 <+43>:  movb   0x416a8dad(%rip), %al     ; _UIInternalPreference_UITableViewEnableAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy + 4
    0x7fff48260caf <+49>:  andb   $0x1, %al
    0x7fff48260cb1 <+51>:  je     0x7fff48260d2d            ; <+175>
    0x7fff48260cb3 <+53>:  leaq   0x416c3ffe(%rip), %rax    ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersion
    0x7fff48260cba <+60>:  movl   (%rax), %eax
    0x7fff48260cbc <+62>:  testl  %eax, %eax
    0x7fff48260cbe <+64>:  je     0x7fff48260d3e            ; <+192>
    0x7fff48260cc0 <+66>:  cmpl   $0xd0000, %eax            ; imm = 0xD0000 
    0x7fff48260cc5 <+71>:  jb     0x7fff48260d2d            ; <+175>
    0x7fff48260cc7 <+73>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff48260cca <+76>:  callq  0x7fff486252fa            ; symbol stub for: objc_opt_class
    0x7fff48260ccf <+81>:  movq   0x41607402(%rip), %rsi    ; "_isInternalTableView"
    0x7fff48260cd6 <+88>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff48260cd9 <+91>:  callq  *0x3e51a641(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff513f7780: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff48260cdf <+97>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff48260ce1 <+99>:  jne    0x7fff48260d2d            ; <+175>
    0x7fff48260ce3 <+101>: movq   0x3e519b46(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff89ea06a0: _NSConcreteStackBlock
    0x7fff48260cea <+108>: movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x7fff48260cee <+112>: movl   $0xc2000000, %eax         ; imm = 0xC2000000 
    0x7fff48260cf3 <+117>: movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x7fff48260cf7 <+121>: leaq   0x46728(%rip), %rax       ; __UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy_block_invoke
    0x7fff48260cfe <+128>: movq   %rax, -0x28(%rbp)
    0x7fff48260d02 <+132>: leaq   0x3e51d237(%rip), %rax    ; __block_descriptor_40_e8_32s_e5_v8?0l
    0x7fff48260d09 <+139>: movq   %rax, -0x20(%rbp)
    0x7fff48260d0d <+143>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff48260d10 <+146>: callq  *0x3e51a61a(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff51411350: objc_retain
    0x7fff48260d16 <+152>: movq   %rax, -0x18(%rbp)
    0x7fff48260d1a <+156>: cmpq   $-0x1, 0x416ca5c6(%rip)   ; _UIInternalPreference_TableViewReorderingUsesDragAndDrop_block_invoke_10.__s_category + 7
    0x7fff48260d22 <+164>: jne    0x7fff48260d52            ; <+212>
    0x7fff48260d24 <+166>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff48260d27 <+169>: callq  *0x3e51a5fb(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff51411000: objc_release
    0x7fff48260d2d <+175>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff48260d30 <+178>: addq   $0x30, %rsp
    0x7fff48260d34 <+182>: popq   %rbx
    0x7fff48260d35 <+183>: popq   %r14
    0x7fff48260d37 <+185>: popq   %rbp
    0x7fff48260d38 <+186>: jmpq   *0x3e51a5ea(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff51411000: objc_release
    0x7fff48260d3e <+192>: movl   $0xd0000, %edi            ; imm = 0xD0000 
    0x7fff48260d43 <+197>: callq  0x7fff48093724            ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnOrAfter
    0x7fff48260d48 <+202>: testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff48260d4a <+204>: jne    0x7fff48260cc7            ; <+73>
    0x7fff48260d50 <+210>: jmp    0x7fff48260d2d            ; <+175>
    0x7fff48260d52 <+212>: leaq   0x416ca58f(%rip), %rdi    ; UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy.once
    0x7fff48260d59 <+219>: leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %r14
    0x7fff48260d5d <+223>: movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff48260d60 <+226>: callq  0x7fff48624f8e            ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
    0x7fff48260d65 <+231>: movq   0x20(%r14), %rax
    0x7fff48260d69 <+235>: jmp    0x7fff48260d24            ; <+166>
```

Can you please help me to remove the warning?

Comment: The problem is that's intel assembly language. You need to debug it with ARM assembly language on newer equipment or get a microscope on the motherboard. No just kidding, check out the backtrace and see my answer for some debugging tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You added constraint before you add your view to view hierarchy. Thas is why you get this error.
Be sure that turn by turn adding, for example :

```
view.addSubview(tableView) // 1
// 2 and start adding constraints..
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
...
```

Comment: Does not adding constraint before adding the view to view hierarchy give you run time error?

Comment: @zeytin, NO! Your answer is a good solution to a very different problem than this question is about.   You are referring to a error message for a much more common situation that occurs when you're doing autolayout programmatically and forget to do the addSubview() line before activating the constraint.

Comment: this did not help me.

Answer (score 10):

*This is an answer to the question, as well a very basic XCode debugging tutorial, for when you run into problems like this. It can be confusing if you're new to this stuff, and not that easy to figure out from Googling.*

XCode offers a helpful debugging tip by mentioning the following *symbolic* breakpoint in the console AutoLayout warning message. You can create, then optionally enable or disable break in XCode's remembered breakpoints list (the second one from the right):
[image]
 The breakpoint, when created and enabled, causes XCode pause before generating the Autolayout warnings, letting you examine the call stack and/or debug your code.

```
UITableViewAlertForLayoutOutsideViewHierarchy
```

When that breakpoint is hit, the XCode debugger stops within some really cryptic looking assembly language code, which isn't helpful to most mortals. Not only is it obtuse looking, it's out-of-context and way upstream, downstream or sidestream of the problem you're trying to solve. The helpful part is the stack backtrace that should show you more-or-less where everything went to hell in your code.

The backtrace should be visible in the lefthand debugging panel of XCode. Alternatively, you can type `bt` at lldb prompt in the XCode console (when the app stopped at a breakpoint or paused).

The backtrace will show you exactly which table reload flow caused the problem, which is usually a huge clue and often all that's needed to figure out what happened.

---

> <sub>Note: If you don't see backtrace in XCode's left-hand panel, be sure there's no text in text field at bottom of the lefthand debug panel. It's a text filter, and if the text in that field doesn't match something in that panel, nothing appears in panel! It actually happens to me enough to point it out here...</sub>
>
> <sub>So.. why would there be text in that filter field? Because I occasionally enter a UIView's hex address (copy/paste it into the filter field from autolayout warnings in the XCode console) to find the 'offending view' in 3D view browser's view hierarchy (more about that in asecond).
>
>  Those warnings are for constraints that have default priority 1000 that MUST be satisfied, but AutoLayout determined were unsatisfiable. *Note: If you want the constraints to be unsatisfiable w/o hitting XCode error/warning, set the constraint's priority lower than 1000.*
>
>
>
> <sub>Note about 3D UIView visualizer tool: You can bring up 3D view visualizer by clicking the icon that looks like three parallel squares on one of the lower button bars of the XCode panels. (If you click the triple-squares and the visualizer fails to render,and console log looks like it crashed, try clicking the 3-squares icon again... usually works 2nd time in those cases). 
>
>  With the 3D visualizer showing, you can sometimes figure out which view autolayout is warning about in the console by searching for the view's address in the by entering it into the aforementioned filter field.</sub></sub>

---

### Case study of how I just debugged a problem:

---

- I got the warning (detailed in the original question), because I called `tableView.reload()` from  `viewWillAppear()`. (Actually from in a function I called from `viewWillAppear()`)
  This error was confusing because it occurred:
  1.  *After* adding constraints
        2.  tableView had been added as a subview of viewController's view
- With debugger stopped at aforementioned breakpoint, I verified that indeed, the tableView's Window reference was nil ... (by typing `p tableView.window` at the `lldb` prompt).
- Then I asked myself how it was possible the tableView is not in the Window hierarchy. Then dawns on me that invoking this kind of thing from `viewWillAppear()` is a bad because, at that point, the view hierarchy is *about* to appear but has *not* appeared yet!

  Yet I definitely must have my table reloaded each time the viewcontroller loads, because I need to pre-select a certain cell in the table. Thus `viewDidLoad()` is not the right place either. :-(
- Finally I wondered if **`viewDidAppear()`** was the right place, and, ... yes, it is. It works perfectly and makes perfect sense.

> ### BOGUS ANSWER ALERT!
>
> There's another answer to this question that says you get the warning shown in original question when you forget to add the view as a subview.
>
> That's incorrect! That is referring to a *different (and much more common) message* you see when you make the more typical mistake of forgetting to add a view to the hierarchy before activating constraints.
>
> But because you generally get that error while programmatically writing your constraint code, it's usually easier to figure out what's happening, although it can take some head-scratching practice to figure out how to figure out the determine troublesome constraint.
>
> It definitely gets much easier to deal with all of this the more experience you have with AutoLayout. It's a bit of a learning curve but it's logical and consistent, with just a few quirks.

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful. I like your style of debugging and addressing issues when they pop up while developing. I have learnt a lot

Answer (score 6):

In my case the answers provided didn't help. Changing my DiffableDataSource snapshot implementation from this:

```
dataSource.apply(snapShot, animatingDifferences: true)
```

to this:

```
dataSource.apply(snapShot, animatingDifferences: false)
```

Fixed the error.

Comment: It gets dead lock in case of changing to animatingDifferences: false, weirdly...

Comment: Never had this problem in my app, and it shouldn't deadlock in any case due to changing the animation - likely something else is broken?

Comment: Yeah, agree. Very weird reason. It shows the message about accessing applySnapshot function from one thread. However, as far as I know, I am calling apply snapshot from main thread only. What might be the possible reasons?

Comment: This was the problem I encountered, disabling animation did the fix for me !

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to find a line that is causing this issue and wrap it into `DispatchQueue.main.async`. For me, that was this line:

```
guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? MyCell else { return }
```

which was executed before the view is fully loaded.

Comment: Mine also was loading files before tableView lays out, thats was the problem

Answer (score -2):

1. Check if you are trying to access tableView properties in

viewDidAppear

then change that to

viewWillAppear

So this way you now tableView is definitely present.

3. Another option is remove all ? (optionals) from "tableView?." to "tableView."  This way it will crash right where the problem is.

Answer (score -3):

I've just solved this problem, and it's really tricky. It took me half a day.

The solution is:

1.Put your UITableView inside a UIView, and set the UITableView constraint to be the same size as the UIView,

2.Then change the UIView's Y and Height by monitoring the scrolling coordinates.

This will give you the effect you want. Don't change the size of the UITableView directly, just wrap it one layer.